# Django does not work after shutdown the PC

Tags: python, django

Everything worked perfectly, I turned off the computer and Django's project no longer works on any computer. The project does not recognize the module `utils`.

When I try to do `python manage.py runserver` I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named custom_rest_permissions
```

But my own modules are there and I can access with the Eclipse link if I press on them... Eclipse autocomplete the imports too and does not work anyway. Everything worked perfectly before I turned off the computer.

I attach a picture.
[image]

Comment: Were you working in a virtual environment? If so have you remembered to activate it? ( `source path_to_venv/bin/activate`)

Comment: I fixed it creating a new project and copying the files one to one... I don't know what happened.